# How to automatically send out non-team member emails after github milestone has been closed?

Tags: github

After a github milestone has been closed, I want to have github configured so that it automatically sends an email that the milestone has just closed to a non-team member (my CEO)?

Is there a simple configuration option I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [Repo Hooks API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) and get notified either by a JSON HTTP Request or subscribing to issue events via [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) about milestone changes, or you can use the [Milestones API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/milestones/) and have your repository users manage milestone statuses through an internal application you've purposefully built for notifying other members about milestone changes.